# How do I refresh a chrome app in the chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

So, I am developing a chrome app, and It makes calculations on how fast a straw rocket is going based off distance and time. I need to know how to reset it after each calculation with a button (or some easy way to reset the code). This is my main code:

window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <script src="calc.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- First heading instructions -->
            <h1>Enter the speed and distance the rocket traveled</h1>
            <!-- The inputs -->
            <input id="T" placeholder="Time">
            <input id="D" placeholder="Distance in feet">
            <!-- submit -->
            <a id="L">Submit</a>
            <!-- The place where the js ccan put the output -->
            <p id="O"></p>
        </body>
</html>
```

calc.js

```
function calc() {
    //the time input
    var t = document.getElementById("T").value;
    //the distance input
    var d = document.getElementById("D").value;
    //whatever that number you gave me is for
    var x = 0.681818;
    //your formula in operation
    var fo = t / d
    var o = fo * x
    //gets the output element, and enters o
    document.getElementById("O").innerHTML = o;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var L = document.getElementById('L');
    // onClick's logic below:
    L.addEventListener('click', function() {


        calc();

    });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
```

It would be great to know this by 11:45 am today (may 17th)
Thanks

EDIT

I am in Colorado, so it is MDT time zone

EDIT

It would be great to know it soon, but I can wait until later.

Please dont make fun of me, I am new to Stack Overflow and coding

Comment: `It would be great to know this by 11:45 am today` - Love it :)

Comment: I am helping this guy with his first code (html-js)

Comment: @EthanP I'm not trying to rude :) SO is not here to help you to meet timelines but we will do our best to help you with your issue, provided all the info is present. Though you might want to include your timezone seeing SO reaches people across the globe :)

Comment: oh okay thanks for the feedback

Comment: I fixed it. I am in mdt time zone

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

All I needed to do was add another script than cleared the output's innerHTML

I added

```
<script src="reload.js"></script>
```

and

```
<a id="L2">Clear</a>
```

to my html and reload.js is

```
function reload(){
    document.getElementById("O").innerHTML= '';
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var L2 = document.getElementById('L2');
    // onClick's logic below:
    L2.addEventListener('click', function() {


        reload();

    });
});
```

Thanks to all who helped!